# Twitter oauth 2 Laravel Socialite not returning email in response

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, twitter-login

I have been trying to sign-in through twitter-oauth-2 using laravel 9 socialite but after login twitter does not return email in response i have tried all the methods but none of them are working can anyone help

I have also enabled request email from user in my app and also regenrated all tokens and secret ids then also email is returning null for old and new users and also tried stateless() method that is also not working

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same issue

Comment: @b4tch currently in laravel i have not found any method that returns email we should try some other library for social login i will now impliment social login from angular